# Passing SVG React Component as Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass SVG React Component as props and getting an error `JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures.` I tried to make Icon property as required or to make Icon type as any, but I got the same error.

```js
import React from "react";
import {ReactComponent as RecentGamesIcon } from "../../static/images/icon_recent_games.svg";
import CollapsibleArea from "../collapsible-area";

const SeoSectionContainer = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
       <CollapsibleArea mainText={testMainTest} helpText={testHelpText} Icon={<RecentGamesIcon />} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React from "react";

type TProps = {
  mainText: string;
  items?: JSX.Element[];
  Icon?: JSX.Element;
};

const CollapsibleArea = ({ Icon, items, mainText }: TProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      {!!Icon && <Icon />}
      <div>{mainText}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for answering, but your variant doesn't work. Nothing, I already found solution. Icon is JSX Element: it needed to be called like this - `<div>{Icon}</div>`, but I called it like a React Component - `<div><Icon /></div>`.

```js
import React from "react";

type TProps = {
  mainText: string;
  items?: JSX.Element[];
  Icon?: JSX.Element;
};

const CollapsibleArea = ({ Icon, items, mainText }: TProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      {!!Icon && Icon}
      <div>{mainText}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
import React from "react";
import RecentGamesIcon  from "../../static/images/icon_recent_games.svg";
import CollapsibleArea from "../collapsible-area";

const SeoSectionContainer = (): JSX.Element => {

  return (
<div>
   <CollapsibleArea mainText={testMainTest} helpText={testHelpText} Icon={RecentGamesIcon} />
</div>
```

);
};

In CollapsibleArea file

```
import React from "react";

type TProps = {
  mainText: string;
  items?: JSX.Element[];
  Icon?: JSX.Element;
};

const CollapsibleArea = ({ Icon, items, mainText }: TProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      {!!Icon && <img src={Icon}/>}
      <div>{mainText}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```